# Notice of the city during the installation of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, timezone

Can I specify Yegor'yevsk during installation of Ubuntu?
Please, Help!

Comment: Not all of the cities in earth are exactly provided in Ubuntu, but, Ubuntu can specify which timezone you're now only if you're connected to the internet. So, it will be best if you're connecting to internet while installing Ubuntu. But, it will took longer since Ubuntu will be upgrading all of the system and software right while installing Ubuntu to your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From trial and error ..**

It is simpler to just identify the **correct** timezone, and nearest **major city** (or cities), during install.

Then later, after install, you can search for a closer match.

**Note:** *If you have already selected the correct country/region then matching your exact city is unnecessary. What is important is the correct timezone/summertime rules for your locality.*